# PHP syntax verses ColdFusion

Tags: php, sql

With ColdFusion  you can run as many queries as you want on the same table with identical search criteria, and just give the query a name like this:

```
<cfquery name="getNext" datasource="mssqlcf_PDartist1">
```

But with PHP I have figured out how to name a query. So, when I need to query the same table multiple times I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE.

```
<?php
$dbname = 'pdartist2';
$table = 'artwork';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from artwork
a join categories b on (b.CID = a.CID)
join subcategories c on (c.CID = b.CID and c.SCID = a.SCID)
where AID = $AID
order by DisplayOrder") or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    $AID = $row['AID'];
    $ArtFilePath = $row['ArtFilePath'];
    $ThumbFilePath = $row['ThumbFilePath'];
    $Title = $row['Title'];
    $Dimensions = $row['Dimensions'];
    $Medium = $row['Medium'];       
    $Comments = $row['Comments'];
    $DisplayOrder = $row['DisplayOrder'];
    $Details = $row['Details']; 
    $nextDO = $rom['CID = getArt.CID and SCID = getArt.SCID and DisplayOrder'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);

?>

<?php $nextDO = getArt.DisplayOrder +1; ?>
<?php $prevDO = getArt.DisplayOrder -1; ?> 

<?php
$dbname = 'pdartist2';
$table = 'artwork';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AID from artwork where CID = getArt.CID and SCID = getArt.SCID and DisplayOrder = $nextDO") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Each query will work alone, but not when there is more than one of them. Like I said, in ColdFusion, I would just give each query a different name.

Comment: Please show the rest of your PHP code. What you have posted will not result in any syntax errors. Most likely you could be missing a semicolon on the line before the error (or many other possibilities)

Comment: <?php
 $dbname = 'pdartist2';
    $table = 'artwork';
 $query = ("SELECT AID from artwork where CID = getArt.CID and SCID = getArt.SCID and DisplayOrder = $nextDO")
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AID from artwork where CID = getArt.CID and SCID = getArt.SCID and DisplayOrder = $nextDO")
or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

Comment: <?php
 $dbname = 'pdartist2';
    $table = 'artwork';
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT AID from artwork where CID = getArt.CID and SCID = getArt.SCID and DisplayOrder = $prevDO")
 or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: Yes, as suspected you're missing a `;`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

with PHP you need to connect to DB, your code above does NOTHING, you are just assigning things to your variables. first just like any other language you need to connect to database :

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

and then you need to specify the database you want to access : (ofcourse dont close the sql connection before you run these queries)

```
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

and then you can just send queries to the database

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
```

now if you want to use the query multiple times you can either copy paste the code above or seperate the query and put it in a variable and then execute the variable like :

```
$q = 'SELECT * WHERE 1=1';
$result = mysql_query($q);
```

I hope that answers your questions

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, you have a line missing a semicolon at the end:

```
<?php
$dbname = 'pdartist2';
$table = 'artwork';
$query = ("SELECT AID from artwork where CID = getArt.CID and SCID = getArt.SCID and DisplayOrder = $nextDO");
//--missing ; here-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AID from artwork where CID = getArt.CID and SCID = getArt.SCID and DisplayOrder = $nextDO")
or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($query);
 ?>
```